# Can I change the default font size in Keynote

Tags: macos, iwork-keynote, iwork

When I insert new text (insert textbox) or when I type in a presenter note, the default font size is 18. Can I change the default to 24? (I know about master slides but since text boxes and presenter notes are not place holders...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [a solution posted on the Apple support forums](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1923149?start=0&tstart=0). To set the default font size for new text boxes, create a text box, give it the font you want, then choose Format > Advanced > Define Text for All Masters.

Answer (score 1):

There's a fairly complicated method of doing this posted [here](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=850995). I don't believe there's a supported, non-complicated way.

Answer (score 1):

I know the simple but pretty primitive method. You click on text box and new text box appear on your slide. You create 10-20 new text boxes, select all and select the size you need. Now you ready for work :)

Answer (score 0):

Just click preferences - change default new text and select the font and size you want to be there when you click Text.

Oh, wait. That would be too simple. Nevermind.